# Is $ z / (e^z - 1) $ analytic in $ |z| < \pi $?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity

I see that $ z / (e^z - 1) $ has a singularity at $ z = 0 $.

Is $ z / (e^z - 1) $ analytic everywhere in $ |z| < \pi $? If yes, how is it determined to be analytic everywhere despite a singularity existing at $ z = 0 $?

I want to know how to show $z/(e^z - 1)$ is analytic or not starting from the definition of analytic function.

Comment: Can you compute the *limit* of $f(z) = z/(e^z-1)$ for $z \to 0$? Do you know what a “removable singularity” is?

Comment: @MartinR The limit is 1. We can remove the singularity by defining f(0) = 1. But how does it make f(z) is analytic everywhere in $ |z| < \pi $. $ f(z) $ must be differentiable (thus continuous too) everywhere in $ |z| < \pi $ to be analytic, must it not? But $ f(z) $ is discontinuous at $ z = 0 $. Can it still be analytic?

Comment: $f(z)$ is not discontinuous at 0, it is undefined. And if we define $f(0)=1$ it is continuous.

Comment: @Trebor So $ f(z) $ is analytic in $ |z| < \pi $ only if we define $ f(0) = 1 $? What if we do not define $ f(0) = 1 $? Is $ f(z) $ still said to be analytic?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Here the domain is restricted to $|z| < \pi$.

Comment: Sorry, misread the absolute value for the argument (easy to do when there is $\pi$). Actually we can extend to $|z|<2\pi$, no?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(z) = z/(e^z-1)$ is holomorphic in $0 < |z| < \pi$ as the quotient of two holomorphic functions with a non-zero denominator. $f$ has an “isolated singularity” at $z=0$.

This singularity is *removable* because $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = 1$ exists, see [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem). This means that the function
$$
 F(z) = \begin{cases}
 1 & \text{ if } z = 0 \\
f(z) & \text{ if } 0 < |z| < 1
\end{cases}
$$
is holomorphic in $|z| < \pi$. $F$ is called the “holomorphic extension of $f$ over $a$.”

In a slight abuse of language, the extension is sometimes also denoted as $f$. In that sense, $f$ is analytic in the disk.